# How to convert ASCII code from uppercase to lowercase by using AND instructions in asm 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

my teacher  give me a task to convert 'V' Ascii code to 'v'  by using just And
instructions

the problem is And instructions is just can convert from from big Ascii code to
small one like example shown below so guys how can I convert it ?

```
Mov al , 'a'
And al , 11011111b
```

Comment: `AND` instruction can turn 1 bits to 0, but cannot turn 0 bits to 1.

Comment: If you literally have to use only AND instructions, I think it's impossible to ever get a value with more bits set than you started with.  If you can also use MOV or have some known values in registers, then you could use a lookup table.  e.g. `mov ax, 0xff` / `and bx, ax` (zero-extend byte into word) / `and al, [bx + upper_to_lower_table]` to load the lookup table result and AND it with all-ones, leaving it unchanged. I don't think you can generate a `0xff` in a register using AND, not even by triggering exceptions.  (Even on modern x86; 8086 doesn't have many exceptions.)

Comment: You're looking for a solution, which involves (a) an algorithm and (b) assembly code.  Have you tried doing this on paper (without assembly) just using logical operators to work out the algorithm? Do that, (a), first.  Then if it works, take it to assembly.